# Python -- PYMC beta-binomial with shrinkage

Tags: python, bayesian, hierarchical, pymc, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm struggling with the implementation of a Bayesian Hierarchical model.

Basically, I'm trying to build a model with this structure...

[hierarchical_model_picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yort.png)

I've got data for how many times individuals are able to hit a ball when it's thrown to them (modeled as a binomial).  The individual chance to hit each ball (theta) is drawn from a beta distribution of all possible thetas.  The mode of this individual-level beta distribution is itself drawn from a higher-level "player-position" beta distribution that represents the possible modes for all individuals that play in that position.  The idea is to put this all into a hierarchical model, to allow shrinkage at the individual-level distributions.

I've tried implementing it using pymc like this, but it doesn't seem to be sampling properly (i.e. remains at starting values for everything).  Any help appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import pymc as pm

### EXAMPLE DATA

initial_data=pd.DataFrame({'player_position':pd.Categorical([1,1,1,2,2,2]),
                       'player_ids':pd.Categorical([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
                       'total_chances':pd.array([8, 7, 4, 4, 6, 13]), 
                       'hits':np.array([7, 7, 3, 3, 5, 11])})

### declarations
total_chances = initial_data.total_chances.values
hits = initial_data.hits.values
player_ids= initial_data.player_ids.values
position_ids = initial_data.player_position.values
num_players = len(initial_data.player_ids.unique())
num_positions = len(initial_data.player_position.unique())

### SPECIFYING THE MODEL
### overall-level distributions
overall_mode = pm.Beta('overall_mode', 1, 1)
overall_conc = pm.Gamma('overall_conc', 0.1, 0.1)

### position-level distributions
position_mode = pm.Beta('position_mode', (overall_mode*overall_conc)+1, 
                           ((1-overall_mode)*overall_conc)+1, 
                            size=num_positions)
position_conc = pm.Gamma('position_conc', 0.1, 0.1, 
                            size=num_positions)

### individual-level distribution 
individual_theta = pm.Beta('individual_theta',
     (position_mode[position_ids]*position_conc[position_ids])+1, 
                            ((1-
     position_mode[position_ids])*position_conc[position_ids])+1, size=num_players)

### likelihood scoring
hits_likelihood = pm.Binomial('hits_likelihood', n=total_chances, 
p=individual_theta, value=hits, observed=True)

### model construction
model = pm.Model([overall_mode, overall_conc, position_mode, 
position_conc, individual_theta, hits_likelihood])

### RUNNING THE MODEL
map_ = pm.MAP(model)
map_.fit()
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(2000, 400, 1)

pm.Matplot.plot(mcmc)
```